# AttributeError from Django model inheriting an abstract base model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to put together a simple little app that allows users to keep track of their own pokemon. Each pokemon has 1-2 different 'types' (e.g. fire, water, etc.), so I've added in a `clean` function to limit the maximum number of types the user can select. However, when trying to add a pokemon I am given the following error:

**AttributeError at /admin/pokollector/custompokemon/add/**

**'CustomPokemon' object has no attribute 'poke_types'**

I'm assuming this has something to do with the `poke_types` variable not being properly inherited, but I have no idea why that would be.

Here is the code from my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator as min, MaxValueValidator as max
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class PokeType(models.Model):
    poke_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poke_type


#Current generation of games for gen_added field
gen = 8

class Pokemon(models.Model):
    poke_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    poke_type = models.ManyToManyField(PokeType)
    evolves_from = False
    evolves_into = False
    gen_added = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[min(1), max(gen)])

    def clean(self):
        #Allow max of 2 poke_types to be selected
        if len(self.poke_types > 2):
            raise ValidationError('A Pokemon has a maximum of two types.')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pokemon'
        abstract = True


class CustomPokemon(Pokemon):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: remove `s` from `poke_types`, since the right field is named `poke_type`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is problem  in  your clean function. Try.

```
 def clean(self):
        #Allow max of 2 poke_types to be selected
        if self.poke_type.count() > 2:
            raise ValidationError('A Pokemon has a maximum of two types.')
```

It seems you mistyped.
Plus, don't use `len` function. When you use `len`, the count happens on python which is slow. Use `count` function so that the count occurs in database level.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll use the ```count``` method going forward, too

Answer (score 1):

Just had a few typos with the attribute name and having the comparison inside the len() call.

```
def clean(self):
        #Allow max of 2 poke_types to be selected
        if len(self.poke_type) > 2:
            raise ValidationError('A Pokemon has a maximum of two types.')
```